# Nested Object - Interface vs Record type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have Object with unknown length, where every item can have true/false value, or have another Object with true/false values. It cannot be deeper (just two dimensions).

```
const items: SOMETYPE = {
  a: true,
  b: {
    ba: true,
    bc: false,
    bd: true,
  },
  c: false,
  // etc...
}
```

I can make interface with [] brackets, or same thing but as type. Should I use type or interface to checking this kind of object?

I can also use Record inside Record.

They all works, but any of these are more "correct", more common and standard way to do this?
Maybe there is other better way?

```
interface ItemsInterface {
  [name: string]: boolean | { [name: string]: boolean }
}

type ItemsType = {
  [name: string]: boolean | { [name: string]: boolean }
}

type ItemsTypeRecord = Record<string, boolean | Record<string, boolean>>
```

Comment: If you check the source for the Record<K,T> type, you'll see that it's defined exactly like your `type` type: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/654975481f6be9c9c2c018d72fe0ac72942c872f/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1479-L1481

Comment: @y2bd good point, thanks

Comment: They're all the same semantically. The last one appears to be most readable to me though, unless you get more descriptive names for the key than `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As y2bd said, the type of `Record<K, T>` is identical to an index signature:

```
/**
 * Construct a type with a set of properties K of type T
 */
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};
```

In your example, `ItemsInterface`, `ItemsType`, and `ItemsTypeRecord` are identical except that `ItemsInterface` can be `extend`ed (as it is an interface), whereas the others cannot (because they are type aliases).

The only other difference arises when the types are recursive:

```
interface RecInterface {
  [name: string]: boolean | RecInterface
}

type RecType = {
  [name: string]: boolean | RecType
}

type RecTypeRecord = Record<string, boolean | RecTypeRecord>
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type alias 'RecTypeRecord' circularly references itself.
```

The last one fails to compile. I think this is because TypeScript allows recursive type aliases in conditional type expressions (`T extends U ? V : W`) and in object types (like `RecType`). However, because `RecTypeRecord` isn't directly an object type and uses `Record` instead, TypeScript can't tell that the type isn't infinite.